# Does my Schengen visa allow me to enter the Schengen area into another state after I've finished my visit to the issuing state?

Tags: schengen

Does my Schengen Visa allow me to re-enter the Schengen zone after I've completed my initial visit to the issuing country? My visa is still valid for about a year. I'm intending on visiting a different country in the Schengen zone other than the one who issued it and don't intend on visiting the issuing country on this occasion. As my Schengen is still valid, that should be fine?

Comment: Is it a single-entry or multiple-entry visa?

Answer (score 1):

If the visa is issued for **multiple entries**, then you can use it freely for trips anywhere in the Schengen zone after then one you described your application, within the validity of the visa and the general 90-of-180-days short-stay rule.

Visas can also be issued for 1 or 2 entries. Of course a single-entry visa can only be used once, but a 2-entry visa should be good for another trip if you have only used one of the entries.

Comment: Yes, its valid for another year and its for multiple entries. I've finished the first trip already and I'm back home again. Can I visit a different country on its own without visiting the issuing country at all?